# Running functions sequentially in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Good day all,
Please I have some set of functions that I want to execute one after the other, for some reason, they don't follow that order. Also there supposed to be an activityindicator showing when I press button to execute the funtions, but that doesn't show up either.

Please I need some help in resolving the issue. Please check my code below, Thanks:

```
startScan = () => {
  this.setState({
   scanning: true,
  });

  //In this order
  this.getDownloadSpeed();
  this.getJitter();
  this.getUploadSpeed();

  this.setState({
    scanning: false,
  });
};

getDownloadSpeed = async () => {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (error) {      
    console.log(error);
  }
};

getJitter = async () => {
  ...
  return jitter;
};

getUploadSpeed = () => {
  ...
  return speed;
};

render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.scanButton}>
        {!this.state.scanning ? (
          <Button title="Scan" onPress={() => this.startScan()} />
        ) : (
          <View style={{marginTop: 5}}>
            <ActivityIndicator
              size="large"
              color="#00ff00"
              animating={this.state.scanning}
            />
            <Button title="Stop" onPress={() => this.stopScan()} />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
   )
};
```

Thanks

Tim

Comment: I guess you're using `await` inside of `...` within your `aync`. If so, you should make `startScan` an `async` function, andadd `await` in front of  `this.getDownloadSpeed();`
 and `this.getJitter();`

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons, I did exactly as you said and also what was said below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with await

```
startScan = async () => {
  this.setState({
   scanning: true,
  });

  //In this order
 await this.getDownloadSpeed();
 await this.getJitter();
 await this.getUploadSpeed();

  this.setState({
    scanning: false,
  });
};
```